# Port forwarding not working in dd-wrt

Tags: port-forwarding, dd-wrt

I just bought a Netgear (3700v4) wireless router to replace another one (3700v1) which failed. A friend had helped me get port forwarding working on the original one. One of the important things that it was doing was exposing Outlook Web Access. My laptop accessed it (Outlook using http access), and I could access it via a browser, and my cell phone accessed it. Now, none of those things works.

When I got the new router, other devices on my network connected automatically (DHCP), and it was pretty easy to set up wireless, but I can't get the port forwarding to work. All I did was add a few lines on the NAT screen:

[image]

Is there anything else I need to do? (I clicked Apply Changes, then later rebooted the router). How can I troubleshoot and fix this? It would sure be nice to have e-mail back on my phone and laptop!

**UPDATE:**
By the way, I have Microsoft Small Business Server installed on my own server. That's where Exchange (OWA) is running.

Thanks for the help. Let me know any other info I can provide.

Thanks, 
Jay

Comment: What you have done is how you port forward within DD-WRT.  How do you know its not working?  Are you sure the ip addresses are correct?

Comment: I used "ipconfig /all" to get the IP addresses for my server (for OWA and FTP) and my PC (for remote access). I know it's not working because my phone isn't retrieving e-mails and I can't use OWA.

Comment: So you are _hosting_ OWA?

Comment: Yes. It's on my personal server. Let me clarify that in the question.

Comment: Could you test with [yougetsignal.com](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) (and test each port by filling it in and pressing Check) to see if the ports are really open?

Comment: I use the "port range forwarding" tab, it's much more user-friendly

Answer (score 6):

You need to fill the `Source Net` field. If you want all requests from no matter which host to be forwarded, that field should be:

```
   0.0.0.0/0
```

If instead you only want users from the site with IP address 1.2.3.4 to be properly re-directed, then you should fill the field with

```
   1.2.3.4/255.255.255.255
```

or, more simply,

```
   1.2.3.4
```

This is a picture of one of my routers' port forwarding page, working just fine:

[image]

Comment: My wireless router (the one with dd-wrt installed on it) plugs into my cable modem which has a static IP address. Should I use that IP or 0.0.0.0/0? I would like to be able to hit OWA, FTP, remote, etc., from any computer I happen to be using.

Comment: Then the correct way is to use 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Great. I'll try it when I get home tonight. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I added 0.0.0.0/0 to all three entries, then clicked Apply, then rebooted the router a while later. I still cannot access OWA (didn't try the other two). Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: @birdus Have you tried from within your own network or from outside? Many routers prevent requests from LAN to go out and come back on the WAN side.

Comment: Well, my laptop connects to my Exchange server via HTTP. That always worked before, but isn't now. It always worked no matter where I was, including from home.

Comment: Also, hitting just my domain name (which is mapped to the IP of my router—I guess I should verify that) doesn't work. That should hit my Small Business Server machine. Do I need to add another entry in the port forwarding for that?

Comment: @birdus I updated my post to include a picture of the Port Forwarding page in one of my routers. It works just fine. This makes me think there might different problems with your router.

Comment: I just tried pinging my domain (home.birdus.com) and that doesn't work. I wouldn't have thought my static IP would have changed, but I guess I need to investigate that.

Comment: I was having issues using 0.0.0.0, adding the /0 fixed it right up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow port forwarding doesnt work on my NetGear R7000. I had to manually enter this command under Administration > Commands in order to forward 8080 port...

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -d <WAN_IP> -j DNAT --to <LAN_IP>:8080`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with port forward but was able to fix it by assigning the port forward via command (CLI), I used the below syntax to get it working

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:80
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Just change the ports & IP to suit your needs, also a reboot will clear this so you need to save startup to make it permanent.